# How can I print the mean of key values of a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, mean

**Python Question:**

I've been trying to get Python 3 to print the mean, sum/len of my dictionary.

I've been looking at methods on stack overflow of how to find the mean of values in a dictionary but every time I try to do it using the keys of values in a dictionary I am riddled with errors. I was able to get the len to work but dividing it doesn't work.

*TL:DR *How do I print the mean of values from a Dictionary? on the commented line.*

I have cleaned out my code and left an empty line to put in the correct code.

```
import operator
"Dictionary"
time = {
        'Kristian':19,
        'Alistair':27,
        'Chris':900,
        'Maxi':50, 
        'Jack':15,
        'Milk Man':1
        }
print(time)
print ("-------------------------------")
"Printing the List"
for xyz in time:
    print ("-------------------------------")
    print("\nStudent Name: ", xyz,"\n Time: ", time[xyz],"seconds\n")

"Printing the Results"
def results():
    print ("-------------------------------")
    print("\nThe Fastest Time is: ",(time[min(time, key=time.get)]),"seconds")
    print("\nThe Slowest Time is: ",(time[max(time, key=time.get)]),"seconds")
    print("\nNo. of Competitors: ",len(time))
"//////////Here is where I want to print the mean score\\\\\\\\\\"

results()

"Adding to the Results"
def question():
    person = input("\nPlease enter the student's name: ")
    secs = int(input("Please enter the student's time in seconds: "))
    print("The results you have added are:")
    print("\nStudent Name: ", person,"\n Time: ", secs,"seconds\n")
    sure = input("Are you sure? ").lower()
    if sure in ("no", "n", "nope"):
        question()
    else:
        time.update({person:secs})
        print("Student has been added successfully.")
        results()

"Running the loop"
question()
```

Comment: By `mean` of key, do you mean the `mean` of all the values in the dict? Since keys are unique in Python dictionary, *"mean of key value"* is not making much sense over here

Comment: Yes I mean to take all the numbers from the values in the dictionary and print their mean.

Comment: Eg have python take the values: 19+27+900+50+15+1 / len(time) to find the mean and have python display The mean is : 168 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean the *values* of the dictionary, not the *keys*, right? then this would work (using [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean)):

```
from statistics import mean
time = {
        'K':19,
        'Al':27,
        'Chris':900,
        'Max':50,
        'Jack':15,
        'Milk Man':1
        }

print(mean(time.values()))  # 168.66666666666666
```

using `dict.values` you could also easily get the maximal value a little simpler:

```
print(max(dct.values()))
```

maybe `time` is not the best name for the dictionary; there is a module in the standard library called `time`. you'd overwrite this module should you import it in the same file.

Comment: I think that is probably why I am getting issues. I will try now.

Comment: This has worked for me. Thank you very much I had been scratching my head for a long time with this.

Comment: Wow. I never used statistics library

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: that is a first for me as well!

Comment: @hiroprotagonist May I ask, How do I round this by two decimal places? Do I have to store as a variable first?

Comment: if you want to round only while printing (and not to do further calculations) you could to this: `m=168.666666; print('{:.2f}'.format(m)) # -> 168.67`. documented in [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

Answer (score 0):

`dict.values()` returns the *list* of all the values in the Python dictionary. In order to calculate the mean, you may do:

```
>>> time_values = list(time.values())
#                  ^  Type-cast it to list. In order to make it
#                     compatible with Python 3.x    

>>> mean = sum(time_values)/float(len(time_values))
#                             ^ in order to return the result in float.
#                               division on two `int` returns int value in Python 2
```

The value hold by `mean` will be:

```
>>> mean
168.66666666666666
```

Comment: actually `values` is a [*view*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) and not a *list*, right? ...at least in python 3.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that has helped me add another answer to my program.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist you are absolutely correct. It just skipped from my mind.